# Unix redirecting csv file

Tags: unix, redirect, csv, cut

Just starting out in Unix and need t workout this:-

I have a csv file with 3 columns.
Using Terminal in Unix I need to cut the columns and get each column to create a text file of the info in the column.

Col 1    Col 2    Col 3

col1.txt col2.txt col3.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This "oneliner" script should help :) Just insert your CSV data into q.csv file or change the file name in the script.

```
 for i in `cat q.csv`; do  echo $i|awk  -F, ' { print $1 } ' >> 1.txt  ; echo $i|awk  -F, ' { print $2 } ' >> 2.txt; echo $i|awk  -F, ' { print $3 } ' >> 3.txt; done
```

Comment: I could not actually get the column data to show in the text files, all that was coming up was 3 text files with the name.csv inside them.

Comment: My mistake, I named the file wrong! Yours works great, just had to change the final { print $1 } to { print $3 }. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Are you familiar with [awk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Awk)?

Assuming you have a csv file, with columns separated using commas, the following will output only the 2nd column:

```
awk -F "," '{print $2}' yourFilename.txt
```

Comment: Not familiar with awk, been using cut so farie:cut -f 2 -d "," numbers.csv |

Comment: for this task, cut is appropriate